# Update OSGi Bundle in Apache Geronimo

Tags: apache, maven, httpclient, osgi-bundle, geronimo

I am an absolute novice with Apache Geronimo, so my forgive my obvious ignorance.

Apache Geronimo ships with older versions of the HTTPCore and HTTPClient libraries.  The current version of OpenID requires at least v4.1 of both HTTPCore and HTTPClient.  I have found the OSGi Bundle page in the Geronimo Console, and see how to use this to install a new bundle.  I also see that existing bundles have an "update" option, although this does not seem to update either of these bundles to the latest version.

Is there an easy magical way to just update these?  If I need to download bundles for the appropriate version, where, exactly, would I go to download them?  I've located and downloaded JARs for these two libraries, and have included them in my project and been able to package it with Maven, but this doesn't (apparently) deploy the updated versions into Geronimo (i.e., it loads the old versions and I get runtime errors).

If I had bundles for the later version, the UI is pretty obvious as to how to install them - will that replace the existing version, or will I then have both versions installed?  Will this present a runtime issue?  If so, how do I remove the exiting bundle (I see no way via the UI to accomplish this).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

David Mullin